# Check if key exists deep inside jsonb object in PostgreSQL v9.5+

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple query to check of the existence of the key inside jsonb object

```
SELECT data->$1 jdata FROM "my-scheme"."my-table"
```

I've run into 2 proplems with this query:

1) It works fine if I pass `'foo'` as `$1` but fails with `"'foo'"` and `"'foo'->'bar'"`. So that I don't know how to reach deep keys. I use `node-postgres`

2) I only want to check if the key exists rather then fetch all data by that key.

So the question is: How I can check if the key exists deep inside jsonb object without fetching all the data by that key?

Answer (score 9):

You can extract the element at a particular path (specified as an array of keys) using the `#>` operator.

You can also check if a key exists at the top level via the `?` operator, though there doesn't seem to be any variant which accepts a path.

So either of these will do it:

```
SELECT '{"a":{"b":{"c":1}}}'::jsonb #> '{a,b}' ? 'c'
SELECT '{"a":{"b":{"c":1}}}'::jsonb #> '{a,b,c}' IS NOT NULL
```

The second is probably a bit more efficient, since it avoids constructing intermediate `jsonb` values as you chain operators together.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": 5
    }
}
```

is valid json.

```
{
   'a': {
        'b': 5
    }
}
```

is NOT valid json. Use double quotes (around keys) when specifying a json string, and single quotes when writing them as postgres identifiers.

Anyway:

```
SELECT distinct true AS found FROM table_name WHERE column_name -> 'foo' ? 'bar';
```

more nesting:

```
SELECT distinct true AS found FROM jtest WHERE js -> 'a' -> 'c' ? 'd';
```

will return 1 record if the key was found, and 0 records if no key was found. If you don't want to specify the path, then I'd think the best procedure would be to write a function / stored procedure to loop through all the keys.

The operator you're looking for is ?

An excerpt from: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

```
?   text    Does the string exist as a top-level key within the JSON value?
```